# Why would you create a Copy of a List to check if the List contains an Element of the Copy?

Tags: flutter, dart

### Copied lists

I stumbled across the [following snippet](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/4d7525f05c05a6df0b29396bc9eb78c3bf1e9f89/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/raw_keyboard.dart#L540) while browsing through the Flutter framework repo:

```dart
for (final ValueChanged<RawKeyEvent> listener in List<ValueChanged<RawKeyEvent>>.from(_listeners)) {
  if (_listeners.contains(listener)) {
    listener(event);
  }
}
```

As far as I know, [`List.from`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/List/List.from.html) should create a copy with the exact same elements as the original list, so they should have the same elements, I guess?

---

For context, the `_listeners` variable is declared and initialized like this:

```dart
final List<ValueChanged<RawKeyEvent>> _listeners = <ValueChanged<RawKeyEvent>>[];
```

#### Question rephrased

Basically, is there *ever* a way the `if`-condition would **not be true**?

#### Type cast in `List.from`

The author did not use [`List.of`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/List/List.of.html), so maybe `List.from` discards some elements when the types of the elements do not match?
But then, the `_listeners` variable already enforced the exact same type, so no element with non-matching types can be added anyway, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that `ChangeNotifier` also does.

The reason for both the list clone and the `contains` call is to support having listeners add and remove listeners. Otherwise, there could be a [`ConcurrentModificationError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/ConcurrentModificationError-class.html).

For example:

```dart
ChangeNotifier notifier;

final listener = () => print('hey');

notifier.addListener(() {
  if (something) {
    notifier.removeListener(listener);
  }
});
```

Comment: I do believe that there is a better solution though. I've opened an issue describing the solution here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59611. I've used that solution for a while in `state_notifier`